# Why template argument deduction doesn't work in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have an issue with template arguments deduction in C++.
I don't know why the sample below doesn't work.
The sample:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t n>
void PrintArray(const int arr[n]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 5};

    PrintArray<>(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler print this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:12:21: error: no matching function for call to 'PrintArray(int [5])'
     PrintArray<>(arr);
                     ^
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: template<unsigned int n> void PrintArray(const int*)
 void PrintArray(const int arr[n]) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:12:21: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'n'
     PrintArray<>(arr);
```

I've found out that the code becomes working if I pass the argument by reference, so the function signature becomes like this:

```
void PrintArray(const int (&arr)[n])
```

But why? Could you please explain me why the compiler can't predict the array size in the first sample, when the array is passed by value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function declaration

```
void PrintArray(const int arr[n]) {
```

is equivalent to

```
void PrintArray(const int *arr) {
```

due to adjusting by the compiler the parameter having an array type to pointer to the array element type.

From the C++ 14 Standard (8.3.5 Functions)

> 5 A single name can be used for several different functions in a
> single scope; this is function overloading (Clause 13). All
> declarations for a function shall agree exactly in both the return
> type and the  parametertype-list. The type of a function is determined
> using the following rules. The type of each parameter (including
> function parameter packs) is determined from its own
> decl-specifier-seq and declarator. **After determining the type of
> each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function
> returning T” is adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function
> returning T,” respectively.** After producing the list of parameter
> types, any top-level cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are
> deleted when forming the function type. The resulting list of
> transformed parameter types and the presence or absence of the
> ellipsis or a function parameter pack is the function’s
> parameter-type-list. [ Note: This transformation does not affect the
> types of the parameters. For example, int(*)(const int p,
> decltype(p)*) and int(*)(int, const int*) are identical types. — end
> note ]

So it is impossible to deduce the template parameter n.

Declare the function like

```
void PrintArray(const int ( &arr )[n]) {
```

Or you could call your original function by specifying explicitly the template argument like

```
PrintArray<5>(arr);
```